# AUTO IP address range

Tags: networking, link-local

I was going thru RFC3927 which stated below statement -

**"The first 256 and last 256 addresses in the 169.254/16 prefix are reserved for future use and MUST NOT be selected by a host using this dynamic configuration mechanism".**

Further:

**"When a host wishes to configure an IPv4 Link-Local address, it selects an address using a pseudo-random number generator with a uniform distribution in the range from 169.254.1.0 to 169.254.254.255 inclusive."**

So which are the specific range or addresses are reserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly as you write: `169.254.0.0/24` and `169.254.255.0/24` are reserved, the rest is used for link-local/zeroconf/APIPA.

Comment: Can you please share an example for clarity?

Comment: Ok Is it that 169.254.0.1-256 and 169.254.255.1-256 are reserved?

Comment: .0-255 in the last octet, yes.